# merge two big sorted files

Tags: python, multithreading

The task is to merge two big sorted files. They can not be fit into memory. My idea is to read lines one by one from line1 and line2 separately and then compare them to decide to put which one to the target file first.

> File 1:
>
> beer
>
> coke
>
> redbull
>
> File2:
>
> cheeseburger
>
> sandwich
>
> taco

The output file should be:

> beer
>
> cheeseburger
>
> coke
>
> redbull
>
> sandwich
>
> taco

I've implemented the idea as following:

```
def read_non_empty_line(input):
    while True:
        line = input.readline()
        if line == "": #end of the file
            return ""
        if line.isspace() == False:
            return line.strip()

def combine_sorted_files(file1, file2, output):

    read_file1, read_file2 = True, True

    with open(output,'w') as output_file:
        with open(file1,'r') as input_file1:
            with open(file2,'r') as input_file2:
                while True:
                    if read_file1:
                        line1 = read_non_empty_line(input_file1) #read one line, skip empty line
                    if read_file2:
                        line2 = read_non_empty_line(input_file2) #read one line, skip empty line

                    if line1 == "" or line2 == "": #end of the file
                        break

                    read_file1, read_file2 = False, False
                    if line1 < line2:
                        smaller = line1
                        read_file1 = True
                    else:
                        smaller = line2
                        read_file2 = True

                    output_file.write(smaller+"\n\n")

                while line1 != "": # continue on file1 if necessary
                    output_file.write(line1+"\n\n")
                    line1 = read_non_empty_line(input_file1)
                while line2 != "": # continue on file2 if necessary
                    output_file.write(line2+"\n\n")
                    line2 = read_non_empty_line(input_file2)
```

The problem is that my implementation is pretty slow. Is there any idea to speed up this task?

Comment: You could use Unix/Linux sort to sort the files first and then merge them using '-m' option of the sort command.

Comment: what format are the raw files?

Comment: @AZhao, each line is a word. The file is just text file

Comment: @Ramana, the file is already sorted.

Comment: but where are the lines coming from? csv? txt?

Comment: Each file is just a txt file

Comment: If the files are already sorted, then you can merge them using 'sort -m file1 file2 > mergedFile'

Comment: @Ramana, I don't know the implementation inside unix. Do they do multi-threading? If not, I'm wondering is there a way to speed it up.

Comment: You could try and see how it performs and then try to improve it if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that your files are very large, you could remove the string concatenation.

Instead of this:

```
output_file.write(smaller+"\n\n")
```

You could replace all examples with this:

```
output_file.write(smaller)
output_file.write("\n\n")
```

This will prevent python from creating a new string from the result of adding `smaller` and `"\n\n"` together, and it WILL be faster. Although it may not be noticeable :)

Don't forget that strings are immutable in python and using the `+` operation doesn't simply add the newline characters to the string. First it must create an entire new string before passing the result of that new string to the function.